# How to calculate sample confidence interval for 33 months consumption?

Tags: confidence-interval

Something is wrong with my calculations
This is 33 consecutive month energy consumption

```
d
array([258350.9, 229512.8, 239379. , 246051. , 250872. , 238581. ,
       260657.9, 217343.5, 238939.6, 248232.2, 222795.4, 193021.2,
       250184.2, 216463.8, 237020. , 225079.1, 234342.5, 222797.9,
       212478.3, 224191.7, 210923.9, 241301. , 216769.7, 177257.7,
       190219.7, 209267.9, 214950. , 196220.5, 208121.7, 203738.2,
       207084.5, 205572.9, 217632.7])
```

Mean

```
np.mean(d)
223192.55757575762
```

Std

```
np.std(d)
20157.208481124897

np.std(d)/np.sqrt(33)
3508.9196030045346
```

I remember general formula

x ± z critical value * std dev/ sqrt(n)

I have checked at [UCD stats](http://www.ucd.ie/statdept/classpages/introquantmeths/introqmchp12.pdf)

223192 ± 6877

I have taken 1.96 for 95% confidence interval. Something is wrong.

```
>>> min(d)
177257.7
>>> max(d)
260657.9
```

It seems that I do not understand why so many points outside

```
216315,230070
```

interval.

Comment: Can you edit to explain what you think is wrong with that answer?

Comment: I have made edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on a confusion between the standard deviation and the standard error. The standard error here refers to the mean and the confidence interval is for the mean. The individual data points have a distribution which is related to the standard deviation. Few of them are more than 1.5 standard deviations from the mean as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are proposing the following model for your consumption $c$:

$$ c_i = \mu + \varepsilon_i $$
where $\mu$ is the fixed mean consumption and $\varepsilon$ is the deviation from this mean, $i$ is an index representing the month.

Now there are two questions one might want to solve:

- Determine $\mu$
- Predict the value of a new consumtption $c'$

What you have done corresponds to the first item. You have calculated an interval $I = (216315,230070)$ such that $\mathbf P (I \ni \mu) = 95\%$. (Note that $I$ is random as it depends on the consumptions $c_i$, but $\mu$ is fixed).

You are now wondering why so few of your recorded consumptions lie in $I$. Looking back at the model, we see that a consumption not only consists of the mean $\mu$, but also the error $\varepsilon$ which is not yet taken account for! This closely relates to the first question of prediction and one can calculate an Intervall $I'$ such that $\mathbf P (X' \in I') = 95\%$.